# How to embed a text file in code?

Tags: python

I have a Python code to run my CNC machine, The code is below:

```
import serial
import time

# Open grbl serial port
s = serial.Serial('COM3',9600)

# Open g-code file
f = open('grbl.gcode.txt','r');

# Wake up grbl
s.write("\r\n\r\n")
time.sleep(2)   # Wait for grbl to initialize
s.flushInput()  # Flush startup text in serial input

# Stream g-code to grbl
for line in f:
    l = line.strip() # Strip all EOL characters for consistency
    print 'Sending: ' + l,
    s.write(l + '\n') # Send g-code block to grbl
    grbl_out = s.readline() # Wait for grbl response with carriage return
    print ' : ' + grbl_out.strip()

# Wait here until grbl is finished to close serial port and file.
raw_input("  Press <Enter> to exit and disable grbl.")

# Close file and serial port
f.close()
s.close()
```

This code opens the g-code file (it is a text file) and executes the lines. My question is can I get rid of the text file of g-code and put it directly in the code above?

Comment: Although you can, why would you want to? It makes much more sense to keep the commands in a simple text file and then read them in as you are. The code will now be plagued with a massive string definition now...

Comment: Because i want to use MQTT protocol for IoT with this code, so i need to send the G-Code to the CNC machine instead of keep it in the text file in laptop.@JoeIddon

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
f = open('grbl.gcode.txt','r')
for line in f:
    # do your stuff
```

You can

```
mycmds = """
put your
commands
into
here
"""

for line in mycmds:
    # do your stuff
```